# Do I get wrong output with BigDecimal ROUND_HALF_EVEN rounding?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, bankers-rounding

I have a problem with rounding of BigDecimal numbers using `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN).

I want to round to 2 decimal places:

```
BigDecimal number1 = new BigDecimal("23.867995");
BigDecimal number2 = new BigDecimal("23.868");
Log.d("tag", number.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN) + ", " + );
```

Ouptut:

> 23.87

But the digit **6** is even, so it should be 23.86 or not?

Comment: The rounding would only be applicable for 23.865 which will go to even

Comment: "round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant"

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Which number are you rounding, number1 or number2?

Answer (score 1):

It's round **half** even, not round everything even. When a number is halfway between two options for what it could round to, it goes toward the even digit. If it's closer to one option than the other, it picks the closer option.

Comment: See the IEEE 754 Floating Point Standard of about one-third of a century ago.